# How to find leaves in a tree stored in a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, algorithm, tree

Previously I posted this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59283760/easier-way-to-find-nodes-in-a-dataframe).

I'd like to know if someone could help on retrieving only the leaves (in case of unbalanced tree) and not necessarily the nodes of level N.

For instance, given the below tree (Note: this tree is a bit different than the one on the link)

```
child|   level|  parent|
   40|       1|      40|
   21|       2|      40|
   18|       2|      40|
   27|       2|      40|
   37|       3|      21|
    2|       3|      18|
   85|       3|      21|
   19|       3|      21|
   14|       4|      37|
   58|       4|       2|
   47|       4|      37|
   34|       4|      85|
   45|       4|      18|
   32|       4|       2|
   47|       4|      85|
   88|       4|      85|
   12|       4|      37|
```

If I request all the leaves of the child 40, I retrieve as leaves : all the level 4 children with 19 (it doesn’t have level 4 children) and also 27 (because the node stopped level 2).

For the child 18, it will be 58 and 32.

Comment: `df[ (df['level']==4) | (df['child'] == 27) ]` is this what are you looking for?, your question is not clear.

Comment: @Ghanem please check the edit. Basically, the input of the function as the previous topic is a child. I would like to retrieve all the leaves of the subtree that has as top node, the child on input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want the leaves, i.e. the children that aren't parents.
You can get them by doing:

```
set(df['child']) - set(df['parent'])
```

#### edit:

If you are willing to use `networkx`, you can use a lot of existing functionality:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

# create directed graph from dataframe:
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='parent', target='child', create_using=nx.DiGraph())

#visualise
nx.draw_networkx(G,with_labels=True)
```

[image]

```
#nitpicking here: your tree isn't a tree: 47 has two parents


# you can find leaves with this function:
def find_leaves(G, node):

    # list all descendants of the node, as well as the node
    d = list(nx.descendants(G, node))+[node]

    # create a subgraph with only these nodes and find the leaves. 
    H = G.subgraph(d)
    return [a for a in H.nodes if H.out_degree(a)==0 and H.in_degree(a)==1]

find_leaves(G, 18)
```

output:

```
[45, 32, 58]
```

#### edit 2:

If you don't want to use `networkx`, you can do the following:

```
#create edgelist from dataframe:
edges = []
for ix, row in df.iterrows():
    edges.append((row['parent'], row['child']))

# recursive function that starts at start_node and returns nodes that 
# have no children:

def find_children(edges, start_node):

    # find edges that have the start node as the parent
    starting_edges = [(p,c) for p,c in edges if p == start_node]
    leaves = []

    # if node has children, loop through the children
    if starting_edges:
        for p, c in starting_edges:
            leaves += find_children(edges, c)

    # if the node has no children, store in list and return.
    else:
        leaves.append(start_node)

    return leaves


#testing:
find_children(edges, 18)

#output:
[58,32,45]

find_children(edges, 85)

#output:
[34, 47, 88]
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. That’s right, I want the leaves. But not the leaves of the entire tree. I want the leaves of a subtree, which will be the only parameter of the function (the top node of the subtree). Your answer is only right for the child 40.

Comment: i must have misunderstood. See my edited version for a solution using `networkx`

Comment: My bad For 47. Each child has only one parent. Is there a solution without networkx if I have a tree ? Thank you very much for the answer though

Comment: Wonderful. Much appreciated